# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect integer value: '' for column '' at row 1 when setting value to null

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to insert a null value into an Integer Mysql column using java JDBC driver.

```
        Connection con;
        con = MySqlConnect.getConnection(accountName);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_NAME) VALUES (?)");
        stmt.setNull(1, Types.INTEGER);
        stmt.addBatch();
        stmt.executeBatch();
```

But I am getting this error :

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'COLUMN_NAME' at row 1

I don't understand why I can't insert this value (also why it is written '' instead of null).
Schema of the table is including

> `COLUMN_NAME` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,

If reproduce an alternate scenario using Float data type :

> `FLOAT_COLUMN` float(10) DEFAULT NULL,

And chaning the setNull line to :

```
stmt.setNull(1, Types.FLOAT);
```

It works (so for the float data type not int).

Comment: Please include the value of `INSERT_QUERY`.

Comment: @TheImpaler I added it

Comment: Does this work for you `stmt.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.NULL);`  or `stmt.setInt(1, java.sql.Types.NULL);`?

Comment: stmt.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.NULL); -> Same exception
stmt.setInt(1, java.sql.Types.NULL); -> does not compile

Comment: @user3696953 Using `stmt.setInt(1, java.sql.Types.NULL)` would set the value of `COLUMN_NAME` to the value of the constant `java.sql.Types.NULL` (== 0).

Comment: Have you tried `setObject(1, null)`? Also, what happens if you execute it normally instead of as a batch (that is, remove `addBatch` and `executeBatch`, and use `executeUpdate`)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes you are right for stmt.setInt(1, java.sql.Types.NULL), I have not tried this code but it"s working for regular int values

Comment: @MarkRotteveel
2021-11-24 15:45:59,521 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  MyClass  - Testing code : stmt.setObject(index,null);
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'MyColumn' at row 1

Comment: This sould work anyway `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_NAME) VALUES (DEFAULT)` (i.e. without using a bind variable) - if everything else fails;)

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using, and what is your MySQL Connector/J version?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>

And for MySQL I am using the docker image mysql:5.7

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Same error when not using batch mode : 

java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'my_column' at row 1
[...]
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)

Comment: Also what is surprising is that I tried to duplicate the table changing the column type from int to float, and the same thing is working using stmt.setNull(1, Types.FLOAT); (when the data type is float then)

Answer (score 0):

do you try:
`stmt.setNull(paramIndex, Types.BIGINT);` ?

Comment: I just tried it, same error